# The 4-way gradient fill. Possible?

Tags: algorithm, html, graphics, svg, graph-algorithm

I need to draw 4 points and fill the area by linear gradient(s), having each of points a different color. Is it possible to do this in HTML5, SVG or any other "browser"-way?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how far browser support is a.t.m., but I find it helps a lot in using a program like InkScape to get a proof of concept in SVG, and then check support in browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experimented the following code in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/y7N3f/) fiddle

```
<svg height="500" width="500">
    <linearGradient id="R">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <linearGradient id="G" gradientTransform="rotate(180 0.5 0.5)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="green" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="B" gradientTransform="rotate(270 0.5 0.5)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <path d="M 100,100 L 300,100 L 200,300 Z" fill="url(#R)"/>
    <path d="M 300,100 L 100,100 L 200,300 Z" fill="url(#G)"/>
    <path d="M 200,300 L 300,100 L 100,100 Z" fill="url(#B)"/>
</svg>
```

getting this result

[image: sample of linear gradients superposition]

HTH

**edit** I've tried to improve and extend to 4 points: see [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/y7N3f/2/) fiddle. Your question was useful to me to learn basics of SVG structuring.

```
<svg height="500" width="500">

    <linearGradient id="R" gradientTransform="rotate(45 .5 .5)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset=".5" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="G" gradientTransform="rotate(135 .5 .5)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="green" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset=".5" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="B" gradientTransform="rotate(225 .5 .5)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset=".5" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="Y" gradientTransform="rotate(315 .5 .5)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="yellow" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset=".5" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <defs>
        <path id="P" d="M 100,100 L 300,100 L 300,300 L 100,300 Z"/>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#P" fill="url(#R)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#P" fill="url(#G)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#P" fill="url(#B)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#P" fill="url(#Y)"/>
</svg>
```

It's worth to note that playing with `stop offset="0"` we get different results...
Here the basic:

[image]

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd params of rotate() are the axis of rotation - 0.5 0.5 rotates around the centerpoint.

Comment: @lucideer - But will system calculate center point for any shape? Calculation of center point is not always easy task.

Comment: @user1215106 No, the system won't auto-calculate so you have to know the height and width of the element being rotated if you're applying a rotate() transform to a typical SVG shape of some sort. Here it's a gradientTransform being applied to the gradient vector, the length of which is always = 1, so it's trivial.

Comment: @lucideer - But 0' and 180' rotations are wrong for this shape, correct? I would expect them around 30' and 150'.

Comment: @user1215106 For a triangle, 0 and 180 (and 270) work - chac has updated with a square now so perhaps this makes more sense to you.

Comment: @chac - I believe `white` color should be replaced by color calculated as a mix of 4 corner colors. In scenario where all 4 corners have same color it should be actually solid fill.